# In Perl can one Select box be in two forms to be submitted?

Tags: forms, perl, submit, jquery-selectbox

I currently have two forms in my CGI script. One of the forms has a submit box.

I am wondering if I can put that same box in the other form so as to send the values from the select box to two different CGI scripts via the two forms.

```
<FORM ACTION="index.cgi" ID="Form" METHOD="POST" >
    <SELECT NAME="stime" ID="stim" SIZE=4 >
    ....
    </SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Is there a way for me to put the select box `stime` into another form?

Comment: What language is that code? It looks like HTML without the angle brackets, but I don't understand the single quotes in the first line

Comment: Thats what it is, I am new to this website and could not figure out how to display the code like you did all of this code is coming from print statements. Thank you for fixing it though that makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: To turn a block of text into a code block, just select all the lines in the block and hit Ctrl-K. It just indents the block by four spaces, so you can achieve the same effect using the space bar if you prefer

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make much sense, because submitting a form involves sending an HTTP message to the server. Unless you're using asynchronous AJAX, HTTP requests and responses are sent by the client and server in strict alternation, so you can't just get your client to submit two forms at the same time. If you explain clearly the effect you want to achieve then I'm sure we could help better.